# How to return to root with popBack using navController

Tags: java, android

Suppose i have 2 fragments: `A` and `B`, and my navController switch between them with a link.
The context is a login/signup window, the user can switch between the 2 fragments for login or signup the application, so the backstack looks like this:

```
A -> B -> A -> B
```

How can i clear the stack or return to the first `A` without smashing the back button?

I have tried `singleTop`, `popBackUpTo`, `inclusive = true` but nothing because the fragments repeat eachother.

I heard about another method that `replace` the fragments instead of navigating, can be a solution to my problem?

**EDIT**

Is more clear to say: return to the initial `A` on top of the stack not on the previous one!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/access_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/LoginFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/LoginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_LoginFragment_to_signupFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SignupFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SignupFragment"
        android:name="com.example.SignupFragment"
        android:label="fragment_signup"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_signup" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SignupFragment_to_LoginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/LoginFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your navigation.xml ?

Comment: Simply popBackUpTo A and inclusive true should do the job. But it would be more helpful if you share the navigation xml.

Comment: I tried popBack but do not work because that function roll back to the first occurrence of `A` but `A` repeats many times and then the result is not what i want. In the meantime we find a solution i try to change strategy and replace the fragment. In this way there isn't a previous fragment to popUp. Thx anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I don't know if i have explained properly the problem, but i have found the solution.

As i sayd in the questions i heard about the replacement of the fragment and that is the main point to solve this type of problem.

I replaced in the code the usage of the `navController` with the `FragmentTransaction`, this object allow you to completely block the stack to grow up using the method `disallowAddToBackStack()`. I don't know why but that function is not mentioned anywhere, i found it by myself looking in the method's object.

Using that function the stack blocks like this:

```
   stack: [A]         stack: [B]         stack: [A]

(click on link) -> (click on link) -> (click on link) -> ...
```

so when i push the back button the app is closed as i want.

**SUGGESTION**

Use the `navController` when you have more then 2 fragment and you want to create a logical path between those fragments, so when the user push the back button you can let the user go back until a safe point in the path.

Use the `FragmentTransaction` in conjunction with the method `disallowAddToBackStack()` when u have some fragments but you don't need some strategical path between them, in other words you are just showing something to the user and you don't care if the user push the back button. **The method MUST be used in all the fragment that do not need to be placed in the stack.**